# how to "flatten" the JSon representation of a composite object?

Tags: json, scala, lift

Suppose I have the following structure I want to serialize in Json:

```
case class A(name:String)

case class B(age:Int)

case class C(id:String, a:A,b:B)
```

I'm using lift-json "write(...)" , but I want to flatten the structure so instead of:

```
{ id:xx , a:{ name:"xxxx" }, b:{ age:xxxx } }
```

I want to get:

```
{ id:xx , name:"xxxx" , age:xxxx  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A and B have multiple fields you will want a slightly different approach:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._

implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
implicit def cToJson(c: C): JValue = (("id" -> c.id):JValue) merge (Extraction decompose c.a) merge (Extraction decompose c.b)
val c1 = C("c1", A("a name", "a nick", "an alias"), B(11, 111, 1111))
Printer pretty (JsonAST render c1)
res0: String =
{
  "id":"c1",
  "name":"a name",
  "nick":"a nick",
  "alias":"an alias",
  "age":11,
  "weight":111,
  "height":1111
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `transform` method on `JValue`:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
val c1 = C("c1", A("some-name"), B(42))
val c1flat = Extraction decompose c1 transform  { case JField(x, JObject(List(jf))) if x == "a" || x == "b" => jf }
val c1str = Printer pretty (JsonAST render c1flat)
```

Result:

```
c1str: String =
{
  "id":"c1",
  "name":"some-name",
  "age":42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a new object D with fields (id, name, age) and load the values you want in the constructor then serialize that class to json. There may be another way but this way will work.

Comment: Well, it was an example. A and B have 10 fields each, and the main reason to have it was not to have 20 fields in C, your suggestion kinds of defeat the purpose :)